# ¿Como cambiar en javascript una variable de color?

Tags: javascript, html, css

No se si se admite este cambio que quiero hacer, estoy pasando mi web a modo oscuro, le estoy cambiando los colores por variables var(--color-resume) en el fichero css, pero en el html tengo este javascript y quiero cambiar el valor para que aparezca #FFF o #000 segun sea oscuro o claro, como una llamada al css para que cambie el valor segun convenga

```
  window.onload = function() {
    try {
      TagCanvas.Start('myCanvas','tags',{
        textColour: '#000000', //este es el valor a cambiar
        outlineColour: '#f5f8fd',
        reverse: true,
        depth: 0.8,
        maxSpeed: 0.05
      });
    } catch(e) {
      // something went wrong, hide the canvas container
      document.getElementById('myCanvasContainer').style.display = 'none';
    }
  };
```

CSS

```
:root{
  --color-canvas: #000000;/*colores fondo*/}
.dark-mode{ --color-canvas: #FFFFFF;/*colores fondo*/}
```

Modo Oscuro

```
(function darkmode() {
document.querySelector(".theme-btn").addEventListener("click", () => {
    document.body.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
})})();
```

Comment: Puedes hacerlo agregando o quitando una clase CSS, **addClass o removeClass** al presionar el botón.

Comment: ¿Hay algún evento o acción que determine si debe usarse el modo claro o el modo oscuro? Por lógica, sería ahí donde cambiarías el color. No sé, es raro lo que planteas aquí, lo más simple sería tener un tema para cada modo y cargar ese tema según sea modo claro o modo oscuro.

Comment: Si el evento es <a onclick="darkmode()"><div class="theme-btn"><i class="fas fa-adjust"></i></div></a>para que cambie el color con css, tengo todo el color de la pagina en root y dark-mode (lo modifique para que se viera mejor el modo normal y oscuro)

Comment: He visto que se habla de `getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue('variable css'); ` pero tampoco se bien como funciona

Answer (score 5):

espero que estes bien , mira yo utilice el siguiente codigo para cambiar el color de fondo de la pagina :

```js
  function changeColor(color) {
    document.body.style.background = color;
  }
```

```css
/*para cambio de colors*/
.colors{
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    padding:10px;
    background: rgb(247, 209, 209);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    border-radius:45%;
}
.colors span{
    position: relative;
    width:15px;
    height:15px;
    background: var(--clr);
    margin: 10px ;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.colors span.active{
    border: 2px solid #333;
    scale: 1.0;
}
```

```html
<div class="colors">
  <span class="active" onclick="changeColor('#34eebc')" style="--clr:#34eebc;"></span>
  <span onclick="changeColor('#8ab5f7')" style="--clr:#8ab5f7;"></span>
  <span onclick="changeColor('#f39ec8')" style="--clr:#f39ec8;"></span>
  <span onclick="changeColor('#fff')" style="--clr:#fff;"></span>


</div>
```

Te comparto el video de donde tome la inf : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LKIk_aCmw0U&t=476s

Espero que te sea util .

Comment: Hola @Alejandra Restrepo, para que ejemplo se pueda reproducir en esta página, tienes que quitar las dos etiquetas de **script**.